# Column to row transformation using Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

```
A = load 'input.txt'; 
dump A;
"0,1, 2,3,4 
5, 6,7, 8,9
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
dump B
("0)
(1)
( 2)
(3)
(4)
(5)
( 6)
(7)
( 8)
(9)
```

I want to perform some replace and trim operation on each field above. How do I transform it back to original format post that?

Expected output

```
0,1,2,3,4

5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is really an experimental question.

Rows to column conversion and columns to Row conversion !!

Yes, By Getting little help from RANK operator I think we can achieve this

I tried the below code for the below input

Input :

```
 0,1,2,3,4 
 5,6,7,8,9
```

In Below Pig script there are two dump statements

```
numbers = LOAD '/home/inputfiles/col_to_row.txt' USING PigStorage() As(line:chararray);

numbers_rank = RANK numbers;

numbers_each = FOREACH numbers_rank GENERATE  $0 as rank_key,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as each_number;

rows_to_columns = FOREACH numbers_each GENERATE each_number;

dump rows_to_columns;--Will give you each number in a separate row..


numbers_grp = GROUP numbers_each BY rank_key;

columns_to_rows = FOREACH numbers_grp GENERATE FLATTEN(BagToTuple(numbers_each.each_number));

dump columns_to_rows; -- Will give you as Per original input data set
```

Output :

```
   dump rows_to_columns;

         (0)
         (1)
         (2)
         (3)
         (4)
         (5)
         (6)
         (7)
         (8)
         (9)


   dump columns_to_rows;

         (0,1,2,3,4)
         (5,6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple replace with regex. Since the `REPLACE` function invokes java `String.replaceAll()` you can use java compatible regex. Here is the demo:

```
grunt> A = load 'input.txt' as (f1:chararray);
grunt> DUMP A;
("0,1, 2,3,4 )
(5, 6,7, 8,9)
grunt> B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
grunt> DUMP B;
("0,1, 2,3,4 )
(5, 6,7, 8,9)
grunt> X = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE($0, '[^0-9,]', '');
grunt> DUMP X;
(0,1,2,3,4)
(5,6,7,8,9)
grunt> Y = FOREACH X GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, ','));
grunt> DUMP Y;
(0,1,2,3,4)
(5,6,7,8,9)
grunt> Z = FOREACH Y GENERATE $0;
grunt> DUMP Z;
(0)
(5)
```

Comment: I am sorry but can you please elaborate on your last line :  "Don't forget to assign the field when you load your input." ?   Also DUMP X results in a BAG and I am not able refer Y= FOREACH X GENERATE $0?

Comment: @BigData the first question: it is not important, I removed it -- only make sure the lines are copied exactly as they are. For the second question: I updated the answer that flattens and splits the chararray so you can reference the first column in relation Z.

Comment: @BigData did it solve your problem? Make sure to accept one of the answers.